# Client certificate mapping with AD

Tags: iis-7, active-directory, mapping, certificate

Is it possible to use Active Directory Certificate Authentication per site basis?

If I enable Active Directory Certificate Authentication for whole server (is possible with IIS Manager) it works perfectly. But I cannot find how to do per site basis - Active Directory Certificate Authentication is not listed in Authentication section for concrete sites - and if I ry to do it directly from XML config, it doesn't work.

I quite need this, because I have multiple sites, some with iisClientAuthenticationMapping and some with Active Directory Certificate Authentication (ClientAuthenticationMapping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out solution for this. It indeed is possible. You just have to enable clientCertificateMappingAuthentication for whole server and disable it on per site basis. The other way (enabling it just where I need it) doesn't work.